# using input field in if else statement javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I'm trying to take an element submitted into an input field and return a result using if else statements but it keeps returning my "else" statement no matter what. I used a w3schools project to begin with, but I can't seem to see what is going wrong.

The user will put a number is the "numSpots" input field and depending on the value of the number, an adaSpots value will get returned in the paragraph id="demo"

Here is my code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var numSpots = document.getElementById("numSpots");
  var adaSpots;
  if (numSpots < 25) {
    adaSpots = "1";
  } else {
    adaSpots = "267";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = adaSpots;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display a time-based greeting:</p>
<input type="number" name="numSpots" id="numSpots" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: you are getting element ..you need to get its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the value of `#numbSpots` by `document.getElementById("numSpots").value`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var numSpots = document.getElementById("numSpots").value;
  var adaSpots;
  if (numSpots < 25) {
    adaSpots = "1";
  } else {
    adaSpots = "267";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = adaSpots;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display a time-based greeting:</p>
<input type="number" name="numSpots" id="numSpots" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I can't believe I forgot the .value

Comment: glad to help, feel free to check the green check button :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

You need to use `parseInt` function to convert string into integer value as text field value is returned as string; and you forgot to get the value using `value` property;

```
function myFunction() {
  var numSpots = document.getElementById("numSpots").value;
  var adaSpots;
  if (parseInt(numSpots) < 25) {
    adaSpots = "1";
  } else {
    adaSpots = "267";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = adaSpots;
}
```